# Global (computer-wide) proxy settings from pac file

Tags: proxy, pac

Our company just changed proxy settings from using one proxy server to a bunch and inserted pac files to IE settings. The problem is, any software that doesn't allow setting proxy script (pac file) explicitly, can't get online any more. 
I wanted to set proxy settings globally in my system and found that proxycfg is used for that, but it doesn't seem to accept pac files.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Andrey

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't a global proxy configuration in Windows (outside of Internet Options) that all apps pay attention to.  Many apps don't use Internet Options, and many of those that don't don't support proxy autoconfigs.  For those that don't you're relinquished to manually configuring them.

What app(s) are you looking to configure?  There are ways to centrally maintain some things to take the administrative burden off a bit.

Answer (score 1):

To set the system wide proxy:

```
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie
```

To show then remove current system-wide setting, use the following:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

Comment: as far as I tested, `netsh winhttp import proxy` works only for direct proxy config, and does not import pac files settings which are in the question.